# Preserving protocol 'delegates' across the App relaunches

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, restore

I am coding my App to survive relaunches as per [Preserving Your App's UI Across Launches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches?language=objc). All is fine, all variables local to the called child class survive. However, I am stuck when trying to figure out how to preserve my custom protocol's delegate values.

E.g. I have two view controllers, one launching the other and setting the called controller's 'delegate' property to 'self' in prepare():

```
    class ParentClass: UIViewController, MyProtocolDelegate {
        ...
    }

    extension ParentClass {
      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segToChildClass" {
            guard let vc = segue.destination as? ChildClass else { return }
            [snip]
            vc.myProtocolDelegate = self
            ...
        }

    }
```

Now in the child class I have 'myProtocolDelegate' variable defined and I override encodeRestorableState() and decodeRestorableState() where I successfully encode and decode all properties assigned their values locally in the child class:

```
    class ChildClass: UIViewController {
      ...
      weak var myProtocolDelegate: MyProtocolDelegate?
      ...

      override func encodeRestorableState() {
      ...
      }

      override func decodeRestorableState() {
      ...
      }
    }
```

However, when I encode/decode 'myProtocolDelegate' property, it surely does not have the desired effect (i.e. protocol doesn't work), e.g.:

```
   override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
     ...
     coder.encode(myProtocolDelegate, forKey: "myProtocolDelegate")
   }

   override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
     ...
     myProtocolDelegate = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "myProtocolDelegate") as? MyProtocolDelegate
   }
```

I thought I could use self.presentingViewController to get the pointer to the Parent controller after the restoration (so I wouldn't need to preserve the 'delegate' value at all). Something like:

```
    override func applicationFinishedRestoringState() {
        ...
        let parentController = self.presentingViewController
        self.myProtocolDelegate = parentController.self  as! ParentClass
    }
```

However, self.presentingViewController turns out to be nil in my case.

I'd be grateful for any hints on how the 'myProtocolDelegate' value can be preserved across relaunches.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621461-encoderestorablestate Have you called super in the overriding methods?

Comment: I think you might need to encode more than the Child controller in order to make it work.